# How to call HTML formated text submitted in database as formatted on screen

Tags: php, sql, tinymce

I am using Tinymce text editor to insert formatted data into database. However, when I call the data back to display on screen, it comes with html tags.

```
<p>testing if <em><strong>its working fine</strong></em></p>
```

However it should have been displayed as "testing if ***its working fine***". Any php string function to display it as it was submitted in database. (Strip_tags shows the plain text, and not a formatted text as it was submitted. Also,you may suggest any better text editor.

Following is the php call to extract data from database to display the result on screen

```
<td class="col-sm-8"><textarea rows="7" class="form-control">'.$msg_rows['msg_message'].'</textarea></td>
```

Comment: Just echo the string out inside a piece of HTML.

Comment: Didn't get that its already showing on the screen then why should I echo it... or above is the code, if you can let me know how to do it.

Comment: You want to display html formated inside a textarea ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sofiene, it displays but with html tags and with no formatting.

Comment: Take the textarea away and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Riggs, and Sofiene... It works.. Thanks alot... appreciate your time and help....